# MYSQL - Finding value on table when all rows on different table exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Sorry if the titles abit wrong been stuck on this for a while now and my brain is well and truely frazzled at this point..

I've simplied the question to the basics. There are 2 tables..

```
TABLE A
------------
-id

TABLE B
-------------
-table_a_fk
-user_id
```

I'm trying to find the ID of Table A using a list of user_ids... and only if the entry exists in Table B for all users..

So if the user_ids were 10,11,12 the query would only return a result if Table B had rows for users 10,11,12 with the same table_a_fk. It's quite important too that if there is extra entries (i.e users 10,11,12,13,14) with the same table_a_fk in Table B then this does not return.. it needs to be an exact match.

I'm starting to think what I need is impossible just in MYSQL and I'll need to process the rows with a more general search... would love for one of you SQL gurus to prove me wrong though ;)

Many thanks in advance for an help and suggestions

UPDATE: Just realiased that table A might not even be needed in this query... as if the user_ids all match then the value of table_a_fk would be the same as taking it from Table A.

Like I said my brains not working atm aha... thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a set-with-set query.  I like to handle this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select table_a_fk
from b
group by table_a_fk
having sum( b.user_id in (10, 11, 12) ) = 3 and
       count(*) = 3;
```

You need to adjust the `in` list and the `3` to match the list of users you care about and the number of such users.  This assumes that there are no duplicates in the table.

Comment: Brilliant answer.. I'll look into set by set queries some more for next time.. all tested and working ok now anyway.. many thanks!